# Uploading files to server using php and phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, upload

I'm building a website and I would like to allow registered users to upload files to my server (max size: 500Ko), and I have no clue on how to do it. The other thing is that those files must be uploaded to the user's directory, and, if a user registers, the directory must be automatically created.... 
I really need help here !

Just so you know, I'm not doing this for fun: it's my "home"work.

Comment: your question is very abstract. it sounds like 'please, do my home work for me'. when asking on SO be more specific. e.g. good question may sound like: i'm trying to implement user upload function but stucked on mkdir function failure. doing so: mkdir($_POST['user_id']); and nothing happens.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to this. I'll try to be more specific next time I ask a question !

Answer (score 1):

To make the directory you can use the function `mkdir` use [phpdoc for mkdir](http://php.net/mkdir) to find out how it works or use Google to find a tutorial.

For the upload part i found a [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) that might be usefull.

The only thing left for you is to figure out how to upload the files to the users directory. If you use the upload tutorial I linked to it is the `$target_path` you have to point to the folder you create when the user registered the account.